# Event handler not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling

I'm creating a simple memory game and I have almost everything done. However, I wanted to be able to set different difficulties with buttons but calling my function to generate the table on the button's click makes the rest of the code void. This is my code. Could somebody tell me why clicking one of the buttons, "#easy, #medium, #hard" makes the table cells unclickable?

```
//Creates all of the variables to be manipulated later
var countCells;
var cardValues = [];
var checker = true;
var tempArr = [];
var winCounter = 0;


//Generates a table with the dimensions specified
var createTable = function (row, col) {
    $('table').empty();
    for (var i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        $('table').append($('<tr>'));
    }
    for (var j = 1; j <= col; j++) {
        $('tr').append($('<td>'));
    }
    countCells = row * col;
};
createTable(3, 6);

//Creates a new game with various difficulties
$('#easy').click(function () {
    createTable(2, 5);
});
$('#medium').click(function () {
    createTable(3, 6);
});
$('#hard').click(function () {
    createTable(4, 9);
});

//Adds a number for half of the cells into an array twice
for (var k = 1; k <= countCells / 2; k++) {
    cardValues.push(k);
    if (k === countCells / 2 && checker) {
        checker = false;
        k = 0;
    }
}

//Adds a random number from the array to each of the cells
var giveCellValue = function () {
    var len = cardValues.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * cardValues.length) - 1;
        $('td').eq(i).append(cardValues[random]);
        cardValues.splice(random, 1);
    }
};
giveCellValue();

//Checks for matches when cells are clicked
$('td').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked') || $(this).hasClass('completed')) {
        $(this).stopPropagation();
        $(this).preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    tempArr.push($(this).text());
    var len = tempArr.length;
    if (len > 1) {
        if (tempArr[0] === tempArr[1]) {
            alert("Good job!");
            $('.clicked').addClass('completed');
            $('.completed').removeClass('clicked');
            winCounter = winCounter + 1;
        } else {
            alert("Try again!");
            $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
        }
        tempArr.splice(0, 2);
    }
    if (winCounter === countCells / 2) {
        alert('You won!');
    }
    console.log(countCells, winCounter);
});
```

Comment: That `for` loop from 1 up to "countCells" - shouldn't that be *inside* the "createTable()" function?  It only runs once otherwise.

Comment: I think it's jQuery doesn't know about dynamically created elements. You are registering the click event before the td exists. You can try using the jQuery "on" method. $("td").on("click", function() {});  If you could post your HTML or even better a jsFiddle it would be easier to help debug

Comment: I don't see where createTable is defined, however i suspect it is destructive in that it completely replaces the table, *including all events bound on the table and/or it's descendants*. Therefore, i suggest moving your click event handler for the tds into the createTable method, or a method subsequently called by the createTable method.

Comment: @KevinB createTable is the function with the two for loops. I've tried adding the button handlers in this function but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler for `td` is lost when you clear out the table.  You need to either use delegate/live or resetup the click.

I took some time and fixed your code here is a working fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/bg2FH/

Noteable changes

`stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` are not on "this" which is the td you are clicking, they are on the event object that is passed to your delegate/click function.

I refactored the button click listeners to call  the functions to resetup stuff.

```
$('#hard').click(function () {
    createTable(4, 9);
    addNumbers();
    giveCellValue();
});
```

I created the `addNumbers` function that you already had to add back the numbers.

Changed `$('td').click` to

```
//Checks for matches when cells are clicked
$('table').on('click', 'td', function (event) {
```

[On](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will does not need to be setup if you add something to the dom after its been called.

Comment: This yielded unexpected results. Here is the full code I am working with if you would like to mess with it.
http://jsfiddle.net/stoney265/4XznK/16/

Comment: There are too many things to count. I would just past your code over mine to see for yourself.

Comment: All of the problems are still present from your last fiddle.

Comment: Now some of the cards show up blank when clicked and make the game un-playable to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you're wiping out the td's that had the click event attached to them. Try this change:

```
-$('td').click(function () {
+$('td').live('click', function () {
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. Use `on()` instead.. with the delegate syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your call to $('table').empty(); destroys the table cells and the associated event handlers. You need to either rebind your click handler for td or better yet use event delegation like:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    //your code here
```

});

Comment: This doesn't do anything either.